# how to manage async socket messages?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, client-server

My socket server initialize X amount of clients on a pool, on a new connection I get one from the pool and start listening on a new task. When a message is received, that client get the socket message and run a new Task that manage the received data while it go back to keep receiving.

I think I am collision safe between clients, but if a client receive the same type of message fast enough the second one could use the same method the first message is running asynchronously.

Should I externalize managing the action to a new class and initialize a pool of "ActionManagers" so each message have his own and only care when they update a shared resource? Any better idea?

Comment: Are you asking about issues accessing data from multiple threads?

Comment: Hmm yes, my server instantiate a client class per connection, this class have a loop task receiving data and when a network packet is received another new task is created to manage the message. Until now, this message is managed by the client class itself, but I was thinking (not tested yet) that if I receive 2 messages that have to use the same method, I will have issues. So I thought a possible solution could be to externalize managing the messages to a different class, so each message will have his own manager.